# Copy a cell from 10 sheets to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a cell from 10 sheets to a new sheet using Excel VBA.

ie

1. values in `D4` of *Sheet1*, *Sheet2* .... *Sheet10*
2. To `A1:A10` of *Sheet11*  (using [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba))

Comment: @jbutler483 Unless I'm mistaken (I don't know VBA at all), this question appears to be asking how to copy the values from a particular cell coordinate from *multiple sheets*, while your proposed duplicate seems to ask how to copy multiple values from only one sheet.

Comment: I was more going along the lines of 'it would be the same thing to copy from one sheet as it would copy from 10 individual sheets' @apsillers

Comment: @jbutler483 Unless you want to do it programmatically. (I don't know if you can in this context)

Comment: - 1 I wonder why was this question upvoted... `I need to Copy a cell from 10 ...` So what is stopping you?

Answer (score 4):

This will copy the cells to **Sheet11** column **A** starting in **A1**

```
Sub GatherData()
    For i = 1 To 10
        Sheets("Sheet" & i).Range("D4").Copy Sheets("Sheet11").Cells(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Naturally you must first create **Sheet11**